# Passing in SQL query parameter from text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have the following code in my C# Winforms Application. I am using SQL Lite but how do I pass the values from my text boxes into the insert statement:

```
void InsertConnectionDetails()
{
    m_dbConnection.Open();

    string sql = "insert into rdpdirectory (company, server, username, password) values (txtCompany, txtServer, txtUsername,txtPassword)";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    m_dbConnection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Comment: The answer from Sudhakar is the solution, however, old style preferably to be avoided is concatenation,   Values ('"+ TextBox1.Text + "' , '" + TextBox2.Text + etc...

Comment: @FeliceM String concatenation in SQL Queries is bad... very bad.

Comment: @EvanL I fully agree with you. This is why I said that the solution is the answer given by Sudhakar.

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:** i can tell you that you need to insert the values directly into INSERT INTO Statement but it leads to SQL Injection Attacks and not recommended.

Try This : **(I don't Suggest this)**

```
string sql = @"insert into rdpdirectory (company, server, username, password) 
                   values ('"+txtCompany.Text+"', '"+txtServer.Text+"','"+txtUsername.Text+"','"+txtPassword.Text+"')";
```

**Solution 2:** So you can Use `Parameterised Queries` to be in safer side.

Try This: Using Parameterised Queries **(I Suggest this)**

```
string sql = @"insert into rdpdirectory (company, server, username, password) 
               values (@company, @server, @username,@password)";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company",txtCompany.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server",txtServer.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txtUsername.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: Can you help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802384/populate-form-values-based-on-data-table-in-c-sharp